# What is the advantage of injection vm into view vs defining it in XAML when using Prism?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I usually define my viewmodels directly in XAML as following:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Otherwise when ViewModel has constructor parameter, with an ObjectDataProvider.

In the official pdf documentation of Prism 5, they define it in the codebehind and inject the viewmodel with MEF/Unity as following:

```
[Export] 
public partial class Shell : Window 
{ 
    public Shell() { InitializeComponent(); } 

    [Import] 
    ShellViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set { this.DataContext = value; } 
    }
}
```

I personally use DI with MEF, but in that particular case, i really do not see any advantages of injecting the VM and think it as an overuse of DI. 
 (assumption: I do not write any huge Unit Test for GUI, which mimics the whole ViewModel, since my unit tests rely on the service layer. And even in that case I could switch the DataContext in a test case dynamically.). 
But may be I am missing something.

So, what are the pros/cons between two approaches?

Comment: It's not MVVM when the View knows the ViewModel. Both are loose coupled. One of the advantages is, that you can use your View for different ViewModels.

Comment: @Rabban: As long as you do not use a DI container, the view always knows the viewmodel, doesn't matter if you define it in the codebehind or in xaml. And since i implement the INotifyPropertyChanged/ICommand and am using DataBinding for each property, it is definitely MVVM. And like i mentioned in my post, you can always change the DataContext dynamically in codebehind, even when you want to use different viewmodels for one view.

Comment: You can realise MVVM without DI. You need 3 Projects to create a clean MVVM Solution. One Project for your ViewModels, one for your Views and one as Application StartProject, this Project will couple your Views with your Models and the ViewModel and View Project don't need to know the other. Your ViewModels can create new instances of ViewModels and a ContentPresenter in Your View can show the right View for it. All that works without DI. CodeBehind is really not adviced in MVVM. And like i stated, if the View knows the Model, it's not MVVM.

Comment: @Rabban: I think you didn't understand what I meant. You have to set a DataContext for the View either in code behind or in XAML (in MVVM it is the viewmodel). And thats exactly the point where view knows about the viewmodel. If you know another way, you are welcome to introduce it. What you are talking about is the seperation of layers with projects.

Comment: if you mean it knows it at runtime, then you are right. But it don't need to know it at design time. You can achive this by separating the Projects like i described in my other Comment. You can use DataTemplates and your Views never need to know the ViewModel at DesignTime. I can give you further examples if you are interested.

Comment: @Rabban: I have my viewmodels and views in seperate projects. But still you have to define your DataContext of your views by setting it to a viewmodel at design time  (or at runtime wit DI container). In your case you are setting it in your application startup project. You are only splitting the dependencies with an additional project. But in fact the dependencies are still there.

Comment: To end this discussion, you're right. You have to set it in the application startup, but only for your ApplicationView/ApplicationViewModel once and not for all other Views. If you want to talk more about it, we can continue this discussion in chat and also in german ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with having your View responsible for creating your ViewModels, but I will just use one as an example; dependency management.  Let's assume you have a VM defined:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel() { }
}
```

Lets assume you had your view created in XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
     <local:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Now, what do you do when your VM needs a service or dependency?

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(IMyService myservice) { }
}
```

Even worse, what if that service has dependencies of it's own?

Well, now defining this in XAML is definitely out for obvious reasons.  If you define the DataContext in code, you have a similar problem you had in XAML; dependency management.  If you had injected the ViewModel, then you would never have to worry about what dependencies your ViewModel requires, and you would never have to modify your code-behind to accommodate a new dependency added to the VM ctor.  It would just work.  This especially comes in handy when your VMs are in a different assembly and shared across multiple platforms, or when you need to change which concrete implementation of a dependency to use based on the build configuration or device.

Comment: Assuming my viewmodel is only used from one view: Would it be still a wrong way to define the viewmodel with constructor parameter as I added to your answer ?

Comment: Yes. This does not solve the problem of dependency management, and things become more complex with handling singletons and dependencies of dependencies. Also, this makes it extremely difficult to change dependency implementations.